# display model base error in view on create rails 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have form where user can subscribe for latest coupons.When i open same store link in multiple tab and subscribe, i get multiple subscription for single store causing duplication of data and sending same mail multiple times .So added validation on model.So the question is how do i get the error to be shown in view .When a user is already subscribed to a store.Since create is making a ajax request..I have pasted the codes below .Any help would be appreciated Thanks

_index.html.haml (views)

```
=form_for([@merchant,@coupon_subscription],:remote => true,:html => { :class => "store_subscribe" } ) do |f|
    %h3 subscribe for #{@merchant.merchant_name} coupons 
-if !logged_in?
  =f.text_field :user ,:class => "input_text email"
=f.submit "Subscribe",:disable_with => "Subscribing...",:class => "store_subscribe subscribe_button"
```

subscription Controller

```
def create                                                            #creates subscription 
return if !logged_in?
return if current_user.subscription_limit?
@merchant=Merchant.find_by_permalink(params[:merchant_id])
@coupon_subcription=CouponSubscription.new(:merchant_id => @merchant.id,:user => current_user)
@coupon_subcription.coupon_subscribe
respond_to do |format|
  if @coupon_subcription.save!
    format.html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => 'Success.') }  
    format.js
  else
    format.html { redirect_to(:back, :notice => @coupon_subcription.errors.full_messages || "Oops something went wrong")}  
    format.js 

  end
end
UserMailer.delay.coupon_subscription(current_user,@coupon_subcription)
```

end

Model

```
validate :validate_subscription ,:on => :create

private 
def validate_subscription
@coupon_subscribed=CouponSubscription.find_by_user_id_and_merchant_id_and_active(self.user_id,self.merchant_id,true)
if @coupon_subscribed
   self.errors.add(:base , 'You have already subscribed.')
end
```

end

create.js

```
<% if !logged_in? %>
$(".store_subscribe").remove()
$(".subscription_feedback").show().append("Login!")
<% else %>
$(".store_subscribe").remove()
$(".store_subscribe").show().append("<h3>Thanks for subscription .We have send you a   mail </h3>")
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your create.js.erb file,

```
<% if @coupon_subscription.errors.present? %>
  $("#id").html(@coupon_subscription.errors.full_messages);
<% end %>
```